# Update values of an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to read a file line by line and store values to an array. and if a username already in the array occurs update existing array for the username, if not create new array.

```
$data[] = array('username1'=>array('failed-attempts'=>'0','ip'=>array('191.25.25.214'))); 

$data[] = array('username2'=>array('failed-attempts'=>'0','ip'=>array('221.25.25.214')));
```

I'm trying to update failed-attempts value and add a newip address  to ip array if array for username exists.

I tried this

```
foreach($data as $d){
    if (array_key_exists($username, $d)) {
           //username is already in the array, update attempts and add this new IP.


    }else{

        $data[] = array('username3'=>array('failed-attempts'=>'0','ip'=>array('129.25.25.214')));  //username is new, so add a new array to $data[]

    }
}
```

How do I update an existing array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
foreach($data as $key => $d){
    if (array_key_exists($username, $d)) {
        $data[$key][$username]['ip'] = array("your_ip_value");
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$result = array();
foreach($data as $d){

    $ip = ''; // get the ip, maybe from $d?
    $username = ''; // get the username

    // if exist, update
    if (isset($result[$username])) {
        $info = $result[$username];
        $info['failed-attempts'] += 1;
        $info['ip'][] = $ip;

        $result[$username] = $info;
    } else {
        $info = array();
        $info['failed-attempts'] = 0;
        $info['ip'] = array($ip);
        $result[$username] = $info;
    }
}
```